# Converting tuple inside list into a standalone tuple

Tags: python, list, opencv, tuples

I currently have a list called TrackedPoints containing tuples inside of it, I can see the values I want stored inside of it in my debugger as a tuple

TrackedPoints: [(350,350),(543,345)]

I'm currently using this code to extract the tuple i want

`StartLineX = [TrackedPoints[0] for x in TrackedPoints]`

This is setting StartLineX to [(350,350)]

How do i go about converting StartLineX into a tuple? I've used the tuple() function but it keeps returning the data like this, which throws an exception in my application:

((350,350),)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you just need the first point, why not do: `StartLineX = TrackedPoints[0]`

Comment: `StartLineX=TrackedPoints[0]` return `(350,350)`.

Comment: @Daniel I was doing it the complete wrong way, thanks for pointing that out, codes working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartLineX = [TrackedPoints[0] for x in TrackedPoints]`: The part between the brackets is called a *[List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*. This creates another list.

What you want is to take the first element from the list:
`StartLineX = TrackedPoints[0]`.

This will fail if the `TrackedPoints`-list is empty.

```py
if TrackedPoints:  # Check if list is empty.
    StartLineX = TrackedPoints[0]
else:
    pass # Handle the error in some way that works for you.
```